# css funciona en emulador mobile en pc pero no en un móvil real

Tags: html, css, datepicker

tengo este css que da estilos a un formulario, cuando el dispositivo tiene un tamaño de pantalla máximo de 767px.

```css
/* CSS PARA PC */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .reservation-form {
    display: flex;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  /* .reservation-form label {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    } */
  .reservation-form input,
  .reservation-form select {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .reservation-form button {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #0077cc;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
  }
  .reservation-form button:hover {
    background-color: #005ea6;
  }
  .reservation-form input:not(:last-child),
  .reservation-form select:not(:last-child) {
    /* margin-right: 10px;*/
  }
}


/* CSS PARA MÓVILES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .reservation-form {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }
  .reservation-form label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .reservation-form input,
  .reservation-form select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .reservation-form button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #0077cc;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .reservation-form button:hover {
    background-color: #005ea6;
  }
  .reservation-form h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .reservation-form button {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .reservation-form input,
  .reservation-form select {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://imorillas.com/witbooking/js/flatpickr.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://imorillas.com/witbooking/js/motor.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://imorillas.com/witbooking/css/booking.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div nombre="motorPc" id="motorPc">
    <form action="https://reservas.hotelesarrecife.es/arrecife_agr/availability?" method="GET" class="reservation-form" id="reservation-form">
      <input type="hidden" id="affiliate" name="affiliate" value="hotelesarrecife_es">

      <!-- <label for="datein">Fecha de Entrada:</label> -->
      <input type="text" id="datein" name="datein" placeholder="¿Cuándo Viene?" value="">
      <!-- <label for="dateout">Fecha de Salida:</label> -->
      <input type="text" id="dateout" name="dateout" placeholder="¿Fecha de Salida?" value="">

      <button name="bookingButtonPc" id="bookingButtonPc" type="submit"><strong>CONSULTA DISPONIBILIDAD</strong> <br>
        Precio Mínimo Garantizado</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https.//imorillas.com/witbooking/js/flatpickr.js"></script>
  <script src="https.//imorillas.com/witbooking/js/motor.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

He probado el código aquí: https://imorillas.com/witbooking/index.html y funciona correctamente como se espera en desktop y mobile en diferentes ejemplos de dispositivos, lo he probado con el inspector del navegador. Así se visualiza:

[image: versión mobile probada en navegador pc]

Pero probado en distintos móviles y se ve así:

[image: vista en mobile real]

He modificado .reservation-form input y .reservation-form select para que el tamaño se ajuste al tamaño de la pantalla, pero no doy con nada que lo solucione en un móvil, pierde el texto del placeholder, se ajusta a la izquierda y se adapta al tamaño del date picker

¿Alguna sugerencia? muy agradecido

Comment: El emulador del navegador es conveniente para probar los tamaños de pantalla pero no funciona como un dispositivo real (porque los dispositivos reales tienen motores diferentes a Chromium y el navegador no representa la página igual). También la densidad de pantalla puede afectar cómo se ve la página. ¿En qué móviles has probado? ¿Con qué navegadores? ¿Es un problema que ocurre en Android/iOS/los dos? (He probado el código ejecutable de la pregunta y funciona sin problemas en Android)

Comment: Hola Álvaro gracias por la respuesta, lo he probado en un iphoneX (el de la foto), Iphone14 pro Max y un galaxy S22, en safari y Chrome, tanto en 4g como en wifi. ¿Cómo probarías de una manera más eficaz en pc emulando mobile? Gracias!

Comment: muchas veces los problems con móviles se deben a alguna propiedad que no está soportada o que sólo está soportada con un prefijo (algo que puede ocurrir a veces con Flex). Para probar en un ordenador sin necesidad de tener el dispositivo, puedes ejecutar un emulador (necesitarás Android Studio o Xcode). De ese modo, no es Chrome pretendiendo ser un Android/iPhone, es un Android/iPhone virtual que funcionará como el dispositivo real.